# how can get red of empty space inside CardView?

Tags: java, android

Dear Android Developers I am a creating cv Android app but there are empty after TextView inside CardView how can I get rid of  that space

[image: screenshot of ui]

below my xml code where I have implemented CardView as parent child as LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        <Space
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/about_me"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/introduction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="start" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Change layout height of card view to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

use this attributes in your cardview you can see the difference

your card do not have elevation and radius and that card view merge to the activity that's why it showing like a space after text use this in your card view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            android:elevation="4dp">

              <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation = "vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/about_me"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/introduction"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="start" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @swedinjonedgarjon i have changed my code use like this

Comment: empty space there still

Comment: there still empty space

Comment: i have commented on my code use that one and make height wrap_content

Comment: and i have mentioned above code is working perfectly in my code

Comment: have you seen the difference what I am trying to say

Comment: what is your suggestion in this case then

Comment: I am editing your code do that give me 5 mins then check my answer

Comment: @swedinjonedgarjon now check my answer

Comment: @swedinjonedgarjon I have updated my card view please can you change one more time and show me the screen shot

Comment: I have updated as well what is your suggestion regarding to improve ui performance regards, Yodgorbek

Comment: add this line in your card view, have you added ?android:elevation="4dp"

Answer (score 0):

reduce marginTop of your text View remove the Space tag also and also reduce margin  of your imageView